# C:/wxPDFView-1.0/samples/simple error build

Tags: cmake, build, pdfium

With CMake i can build libwxPDFView.a library with CodeBlocks(20) and MinW64 compiler
But building C:/wxPDFView-1.0/samples/simple i have problem.
Pdfium libs are at c:\repo\Libraries\pdfium\lib\lib and bin
Thank you.
Jim

> [ 87%] Built target wxPDFView
> C:/PROGRA~1/CODEBL~1/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe  -f
> CMakeFiles\wxPDFViewSimpleSample.dir\build.make
> CMakeFiles/wxPDFViewSimpleSample.dir/depend mingw32-make.exe[3]:
> Entering directory 'C:/wxPDFView-1.0/samples/simple/out' "C:\Program
> Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_depends "MinGW Makefiles"
> C:\wxPDFView-1.0\samples\simple C:\wxPDFView-1.0\samples\simple
> C:\wxPDFView-1.0\samples\simple\out
> C:\wxPDFView-1.0\samples\simple\out
> C:\wxPDFView-1.0\samples\simple\out\CMakeFiles\wxPDFViewSimpleSample.dir\DependInfo.cmake
> --color= Dependee "C:\wxPDFView-1.0\samples\simple\out\CMakeFiles\wxPDFViewSimpleSample.dir\DependInfo.cmake"
> is newer than depender
> "C:/wxPDFView-1.0/samples/simple/out/CMakeFiles/wxPDFViewSimpleSample.dir/depend.internal".
> Dependee
> "C:/wxPDFView-1.0/samples/simple/out/CMakeFiles/CMakeDirectoryInformation.cmake"
> is newer than depender
> "C:/wxPDFView-1.0/samples/simple/out/CMakeFiles/wxPDFViewSimpleSample.dir/depend.internal".
> Scanning dependencies of target wxPDFViewSimpleSample
> mingw32-make.exe[3]: Leaving directory
> 'C:/wxPDFView-1.0/samples/simple/out'
> C:/PROGRA~1/CODEBL~1/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe  -f
> CMakeFiles\wxPDFViewSimpleSample.dir\build.make
> CMakeFiles/wxPDFViewSimpleSample.dir/build mingw32-make.exe[3]:
> Entering directory 'C:/wxPDFView-1.0/samples/simple/out' [ 93%]
> Building CXX object
> CMakeFiles/wxPDFViewSimpleSample.dir/Simple.cpp.obj
> C:\PROGRA~1\CODEBL~1\MinGW\bin\G__~1.EXE -DUNICODE -D_DEBUG -D_UNICODE
> -D__WXDEBUG__ @CMakeFiles/wxPDFViewSimpleSample.dir/includes_CXX.rsp -g -o CMakeFiles\wxPDFViewSimpleSample.dir\Simple.cpp.obj -c C:\wxPDFView-1.0\samples\simple\Simple.cpp mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** No
> rule to make target 'pdfium-NOTFOUND', needed by
> 'wxPDFViewSimpleSample.exe'.  Stop. mingw32-make.exe[2]: ***
> [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:114: CMakeFiles/wxPDFViewSimpleSample.dir/all]
> Error 2 mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:121:
> CMakeFiles/wxPDFViewSimpleSample.dir/rule] Error 2 mingw32-make.exe:
> *** [C:/wxPDFView-1.0/samples/simple/out/Makefile:136: wxPDFViewSimpleSample] Error 2 mingw32-make.exe[3]: Leaving directory
> 'C:/wxPDFView-1.0/samples/simple/out' mingw32-make.exe[2]: Leaving
> directory 'C:/wxPDFView-1.0/samples/simple/out' mingw32-make.exe[1]:
> Leaving directory 'C:/wxPDFView-1.0/samples/simple/out' Process
> terminated with status 2 (1 minute(s), 43 second(s)) 3 error(s), 0
> warning(s) (1 minute(s), 43 second(s))

Comment: The error message `No rule to make target 'pdfium-NOTFOUND'` means that CMake has been unable to find `pdfium` library or similar.

Comment: C:/repo/Libraries/pdfium/x64/lib/pdfium.dll.lib, Gonfigure and Generate are ok. Found PDFium: C:/repo/Libraries/pdfium/x64/lib/pdfium.dll.lib  
Configuring done. So something else is. With this configuration CB produces libwxPDFView.a

Comment: Found PDFium: C:/repo/Libraries/pdfium/x64/lib/pdfium.dll.lib  
Configuring done
Generating done

Comment: Well, so something else is wrong with the project you built. You may report the problem to their bugtracker.